# Можно ли просматривать POST / GET запросы телефона из одной WiFi сети?

Tags: wifi, запрос, трафик

Хочется изучить запросы телефона / планшета через разные приложения. 
На компьютере можно использовать http analyzer, fiddler и им подобные. Но как посмореть запросы из WiFi сети?

Comment: самый честный вариант - поставить wifi точку на компе и сниффить.

Answer (score 2):

Ставишь шлюзом ptraffer

[image]
<sub>(источник: [ptraffer.ru](http://forum.ptraffer.ru/download/file.php?id=165&sid=c611e085e8a01c6d2e6730b7659578fa))</sub>

и там будет видно в том числе планшеты по вай-фай

Answer (score 1):

вообще  можно сделать из компа точку  доступа, то есть подлкючить его проводами к ИНтернету, а WiFi Раздавать   и  просто снимать трафик  любым снифером  с wifi интерфейса (  например wireshark )
Из минусов - сейчас 95%   трафика это https, так что  в теле запроса  ничего не видно.  Методы борьбы с этим-  MiTM , то есть  ставим на раздающий  комп  DNS  сервер, говорим ему искажать ответы для домена, который сканим,  уговариваем телефон признавать эти сертификаты,  на компе  ставим  какой-то https  прокси ( проще всего Nginx).
Или воспользоваться чем- то  похожим на http://www.spy-soft.net/shark-android/